# how to setup s3 so that reactjs BrowserRouter basename works

Tags: reactjs, amazon-s3

I have a reactjs project with the following code. It adds subpath for each url

```
ReactDOM.render(
  <BrowserRouter basename="/troubleshoot">
    <MaterialUIControllerProvider>
      <App />
    </MaterialUIControllerProvider>
  </BrowserRouter>,
  document.getElementById("root")
);
```

Now I want put this static website on s3 bucket.

I tried to create a bucket and folder troubleshoot inside that and put all the build files.

But in s3 i have to mention the index.html

I am not sure how to make this work using S3